# Is there a way to do pagination on a child field of a GraphQL type?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, graphql, pagination, apollo-server

I am working on adding a pagination functionality for the server side of a GraphQL API. For context, I include a sample of the UML diagram of the Products table and its referenced tables from the database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJqUv.png)

The graphQL schema and resolver are:

```
 const schema = gql`
  type Product {
    id: Int!
    events: [ProductEvent!]!
    orderRows: [OrderRow!]!
    ...
  }
  type ProductEvent {
    id: Int!
    product: Product!
    delta: Int!
    date: Date!
    ...
  }
  type OrderRow {
    id: Int!
    order: Order!
    product: Product!
    ...
  }
  type Order {
    id: Int!
    rows: [OrderRow!]!
    customer: Customer!
    shippingDate: Date!
    ...
  }

  const resolvers = {
  Product: {
    events: async (product: Product, _args: any, context: Context) => 
    context.loaders.loadProductEvents.load(product.id),
    orderRows: async (product: Product, _args: any, context: Context) => 
    context.loaders.loadOrderRows.load(product.id),
  },
  Query: {
    product: (_parent: any, { id }: { id: number }, context: Context) =>
      context.models.Product.findByPk(id),
    products: async (
      _parent: any,
      { onlyActive, producerId }: { onlyActive?: boolean; producerId?: number },
      context: Context,
    ) => {
      ...
    },
  }
```

The resolvers for `Product.events` and `Product.orderRows` call a DataLoader and returns all events and orderRows corresponding to the queried `product.id` param.

The problem is that one products can appears in a multiple events (e.g., purchase, loss, sampling) and order-rows. For that reason, I want to to add a pagination functionality for the `Product.events` and `Product.orderRows` when querying a `product.id`.

I have been trying to implement something like:

```
...
Query: {
    productPaginationByMonth: async(
      _parent: any, 
      { id, first, after }: { id: number; first: number; after?: Date },
      context: Context,
    ) => {
      function getOrderRowsWithinRange(productId: number, first: number, after: any){
        // query $first order-rows containing productId $after a certain shippingDate 
        ...
        // return [OrderRow]
      }
      function getEventsWithinRange(productId: number, first: number, after: any){
        // query $first product events containing productId $after a certain date
        ...
        // return [ProductEvent] 
      }
      ...
      // I'd like to return something like this
      return {...Product.findByPK(id), events: getEventsWithinRange(id, first, after), orderRows: getOrderRowsWithinRange(id, first, after)}
    },
  }
```

The spread operation doesn't work and I am now questioning if this approach is event possible. So **question (1) is how to do pagination on the child fields of graphQL type?**

Another question is about DataLoader. And **question (2) is can I overload the Dataloader so that it returns an array of ProductEvents and OrderRows within a time range?**

Comment: For those who ends up with the same problem, I  got really good answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/graphql/comments/w7obcg/is_there_a_way_to_do_pagination_on_a_child_field/